# Libgdx font isn't drawing

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx, drawing

I am trying to create a score text for my game. When i run the code i get no errors but i don't see any text. Here's the code for initizaling the text:

FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("Gameplay/font.ttf"));

FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();

parameter.size = 30;

parameter.characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.!'()>?: ";

font = generator.generateFont(parameter);

generator.dispose();

font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
And here is the code for rendering the text:

Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0F, 0F, 0F, 1F);

Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

sb.begin();

font.draw(sb, "test", 0, 0);

sb.end();

I don't see any text what so ever, thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

BitmapFonts in libgdx are drawn from the top down, so the top of your text is at y=0 and hence the rest of your text is being displayed underneath the visible screen.

As a test, try changing y to something in the middle of the screen.

There may be other issues too, so if the text still doesn't appear I suggest you provide a bit more code so we can help further.